# Bot Telegram problem more than 2 users contemporaneous

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I have a problem with a simple Telegram Bot. As long as there is only one user using the Bot, I have no problems, but when two users run the cmd_2 command, the bot freezes and no longer executes any commands until one of the two users "exits" the cmd_2 command . How can I solve this problem?

```
import telebot
import datetime
import time

API_TOKEN = "API_TOKEN"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)


user_dict = {}
class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

# Handle '/start'
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Hi there, I am Example bot.')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['cmd_1'])
def send_welcome(message):
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, "What's your name?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_name_step)
def process_name_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        name = message.text
        user = User(name)
        user_dict[chat_id] = user
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Nice to meet you ' + user.name)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['cmd_2'])
def send_welcome(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user = user_dict[chat_id]
    st = datetime.datetime.now()
    for i in range(5):
        sp = datetime.datetime.now()
        delta = sp-st
        msg = f"{user.name}, {delta} minutes have passed"
        bot.send_message(chat_id, f'{msg}')
        time.sleep(60)

bot.polling()
```

I would like it to be possible to use the Bot by multiple users at the same time